# remove select2 class from form

Tags: html, wordpress, jquery-select2, html-select

I add my own HTML element 'select' in Wordpress by Elementor and inside select some function from 'SELECT2' set automatically class 'select2-hidden-accessible'. In result my select doesn't open on mobile devices. And I don't know how I can remove this class - when I remove in console my select works. Or maybe can I set function to open my select. I tried remove it in JS but it doesn't work. I tried remove it in function select2 but it not works too. Please help me.

my code:

```
<select id="cat__mobile">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="opt1">opt1</option>
   <option value="opt2">opt2</option>
</select>
```

code in console:

```
<select id="cat__mobile" data-select2-id="cat__mobile" tabindex="-1" style="" class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true">
   <option value="" data-select2-id="5"></option>
   <option value="opt1">opt1</option>
   <option value="opt2">opt2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Plugin id same now change the id on your side